# Inconsistent array keys after unset + merge + add value, versions 7.3 & 7.4

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge, unset, array-key

Code example:

```
<?php

$values = [];                          // start values

$list = ['one', 'two', 'three'];       // some list
$oneMore = 'four';                     // some element

unset($list[2]);                       // unset last(!) list element

$values = array_merge($values, $list); // add list to values
$values[] = $oneMore;                  // add element to values

print_r($values);
```

Result for 7.3.33:

```
Array
(
    [0] => one
    [1] => two
    [2] => four
)
```

Result for 7.4.29:

```
Array
(
    [0] => one
    [1] => two
    [3] => four
)
```

As you see, the **keys** are different in 7.3 and 7.4.

This happenes **only** when *last element* of `$list` array is unset. If some other element is unset, the result is identical.

**Question**: Is this expected/desired behaviour in 7.4+? Or a bug?

**Note**: If an *empty array* is added during merge, the resulting arrays **will** be indentical, i.e.:

```
$values = array_merge($values, $list, []);
```

https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/c/9625fee6-d127-45f1-8c68-3c64bcb87d0c

Comment: The manual states: "Values in the input arrays with numeric keys will be renumbered with incrementing keys starting from zero in the result array.", so this seems looks like a bug to me.

Comment: Better sandbox for presenting the behavior: https://3v4l.org/AOqjB